# Javascript lists. Inputting and outputting values

Tags: javascript, html

I've made a random number generator, I'm trying to add these values to a list so that I can then take them out again as "These were the  last ten numbers"
So far I have this:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<h1>
    The last number was:

    <p id="userData"></p>
</h1>
<button onclick="random()">Random</button>
<script>
    function random() {
        document.getElementById("userData").innerHTML = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I would love any help I could get. Thanks

Comment: If you have multiple `<head>` and `<body>` section, then that is invalid HTML. Are you sure you've copied/pasted your code correctly?

Comment: There is also an error here: `document.getElementById("userData").innerHTML = var number`. Should be `var someVariable = document.getElementById("userData").innerHTML`. omit the `var` to make the variable globally accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a basic javascript-array to save your calculated random-values.

```
randoms = []; // Create an array

function random() {
    let newRandom = Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
    randoms.push(newRandom); // save newly created number to that array
    document.getElementById("userData").innerHTML = newRandom;
}
```

In `randoms` you now have a list of all calculated random numbers for further usage.

To render those values to the html-page, one could alter the random function and add `document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = randoms;`. When adding a div `<div id="randoms"></div>` to the html page, this results in all random-values printed to the page.

Comment: How would I then output the values in that array?

Comment: Where do you need that output?
To the console, you can always run `console.log(randoms)`.
Or do you mean to the html page?

Comment: The page itself

Comment: Add a div where the content should be rendered: `<div id="randoms"></div>`.
Then in the random function, always re-render that div like this:
`document.getElementById("randoms").innerHTML = randoms;`

Comment: I've also added that part to the answer.